# How to add new line to Button from XML

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

In my NativeScript project, I'm trying to make a bottom bar with an icon and then the word that resembles it underneath it. Like this

[image: bottom bar]

Here's the html of what I tried to do:

```html
<GridLayout rows="*,60">
    <ScrollView row="0">
        <WrapLayout orientation="horizontal">
            <Label text="There are no leagues currently." style="color: black; text-align: center; font-weight: bold"></Label>
            <Label text="Contact your commissioner" style="color: black; text-align: center; font-weight: bold"></Label>
            <Label text="to create one." style="color: black; text-align: center; font-weight: bold"></Label>
        </WrapLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <StackLayout row="1" orientation="horizontal">
        <Button textWrap="true" width="25%">
            <FormattedString>
                <Span text="&#xf015;\n" class="fa"></Span>
                <Span text="Home"></Span>
            </FormattedString>
        </Button>
        <Button textWrap="true" width="25%">
            <FormattedString>
                <Span text="&#xf000;\n" class="fa"></Span>
                <Span text="All Cocktails"></Span>
            </FormattedString>
        </Button>
        <Button textWrap="true" width="25%">
            <FormattedString>
                <Span text="&#xf005;\n" class="fa"></Span>
                <Span text="Favorite"></Span>
            </FormattedString>
        </Button>
        <Button textWrap="true" width="25%">
            <FormattedString>
                <Span text="&#xf007;\n" class="fa"></Span>
                <Span text="Profile"></Span>
            </FormattedString>
        </Button>
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

and here's my css:

```css
.fa {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
}
```

However, whenever I try to do this, it comes out like this

[image: result :(]

I'm not quite sure where to go so any help would be great. Thanks!

Here's a working example of my code: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=r8Jodt&v=19

Comment: Include your (“*[mcve]*”) code *in* your question, don’t just post a link to another site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual problem here is that `\n` works only with JavaScript, while using it in HTML (XML) file you should use the encode version of the character that is `&#xA;`, that should give you a new line.

Are you trying to have a custom TabBar for your TabView? If Yes, you may try the [nativescript-vector-icons](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-vector-icons) which allows you to use font icons on TabBar.

Comment: Sorry, you have to provide more info than "not working". Please try to explain post code sample, framework & runtime versions you are using Or preferably a Playground sample.

Answer (score 3):

Use the GridLayout for BottomBar, you can look for the playground sample [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=r8Jodt&v=20)

```html
<GridLayout columns="*,*,*,*" rows="*,*" width="100%" row="1" backgroundColor="lightgray">
  <Label text="&#xf015;" row="0" col="0" class="fa" width="100%" textAlignment="center"></Label>
  <Label text="Home" row="1" col="0" width="100%" textAlignment="center"></Label>
  <Label text="&#xf000;" row="0" col="1" class="fa" width="100%" textAlignment="center"></Label>
  <Label text="All Cocktails" row="1" col="1" width="100%" textAlignment="center"></Label>
  <Label text="&#xf005;" row="0" col="2" class="fa" width="100%" textAlignment="center"></Label>
  <Label text="Favorite" row="1" col="2" width="100%" textAlignment="center"></Label>
  <Label text="&#xf007;" row="0" col="3" class="fa" width="100%" textAlignment="center"></Label>
  <Label text="Profile" row="1" col="3" width="100%" textAlignment="center"></Label>

</GridLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make their position as display:absolute and within the class it should be inline-block. With some margins it should be easy to adjust

Answer (score 0):

I would contain all the buttons in a div, and then each button and label group in it's own div.

```
<div id='button-row'>
  <div class='bottom-button>
     <button></button>
     <p class='label>Label</p>
  </div>
   <div class='bottom-button>
     <button></button>
     <p class='label>Label</p>
  </div>
  // repeat for your buttons
</div>
```

Your css:

```
.button-row {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
.bottom-button {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center;
   // the font awesome icons are considered text I believe, so 
   text-align: center;
   // would also work
}
```

This will make all your buttons in the row evenly spaced, and place your button on top of the label. I like using flexbox because its quick and easy, and mobile responsive. I'm not a CSS pro by any means but it works for me.

Edit: just saw your markup. Try giving formatted string the css of .bottom-button and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

For \n just worked for android.
using hex code 
 also not worked for both ios and android.

the final solution I find  is as below:

(for nativescript-vue)

```html
    <Label textWrap="true" col="0" row="0">
      <FormattedString>
        <Span class="number" :text="days" />
        <Span class="format" :text="'\n' + 'Gün'" />
      </FormattedString>
    </Label>
```